# How can i display the events from the current month only from The Event Calendar wordpress plugin?

Tags: wordpress

I have a small widget on my website that contains a list of events.  I want to add prev/next month buttons to the widget so i need a way to filter the results from The Event Calendar plugin by the month.

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this? I didn't see a list of parameters i could pass to the tribe_get_events array.

This is the code i am using now:

```
global $post;
$all_events = tribe_get_events(array(
'eventDisplay'=>'all',
'posts_per_page'=>-1
));
```

So what i want to do is something like:

```
global $post;
$all_events = tribe_get_events(array(
'eventDisplay'=>'all',
'month'=>'may',
'posts_per_page'=>-1
));
```

Just not exactly sure of the right name for the parameter to just get the current month.

Thanks in advance for the assist :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to get a month at a time with The Event Calendar Wordpress plugin.

The code that I am using is looks like this:

```
global $post;

if (isset($_GET['setmonth'])) {
$current_month = $_GET['setmonth']; // this grabs the month from the url
} else {
$current_month = date('M'); // This gets the current month
}


$all_events = tribe_get_events(array(
'eventDisplay'=>'all',
'posts_per_page'=>-1,
'start_date'=>'01 '.$current_month.' 2012',
'end_date'=>'31 '.$current_month.' 2012'
 ));
```